# Redirect user after clicking on save button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<a>` tag on the page like below:

```
<a href="/-/media/Wallpapers/wallpaper_nokia.jpg" download="">Download Wallpaper</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link the save as button opens up for the user to save the image. What I want to do is to redirect user to the home page **after** user clicks on the save button.

Is there any way to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: you want to add function to windows download popup?

Comment: You can check if the downloaded file exists, but it will be not after clicking save, only after the download is completed.

Comment: where is your save button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```